# I use Geany 1.36 on ubuntu 20.04, but I do not find the debugger pluging, How can I debug?

Tags: debugging, ubuntu-20.04, geany, geany-plugin

I am coding using python3 and I have been trying to start debugging in Geany v 1.36, but it seems that the debugger pluging is not available for Ubuntu 20.04.

I have installed the plugins

```
sudo apt-get install geany-plugins
```

I have restarted Geany, looked in the plugin manager-

I have searched for a while now and I do not find any answers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should compile [geany-plugins](https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins.git) from src

```sh
git clone https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins.git
cd geany-plugins/
sudo apt-get install libvte-2.91-dev
./autogen.sh --disable-all-plugins --enable-debugger --prefix=/usr
make -j8
sudo make install
```